# Error when querying Azure DevOps data using OData feed in Power BI for work item revisions

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I am building a team velocity chart in Azure DevOps using Power BI. It requires planned and completed work items for each sprint.

I am unable to get planned work items for previous sprints.

I tried using WorkItemRevision details through OData feed, but it gives me an error when I try to expand IterationPath and AreaPath details.

The details of the error are as follows (initially I used the simple query

```
= OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/organization/project/_odata/V3.0-preview/workitemrevisions?$filter=workitemtype in ('User Story')",null,[implementation="2.0"])
```

The error is:

> Data source error: A null value was found. For the property named 'AreaPath' which has expected type 'EDM.string[nullable=false]' does not allow null values.

I then tried adding `OmitValues=ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataversion=4]`, but then I get this error:

> DataFormat.error=We expected property 'Iterationpath',but the OData service omitted it from the response data. This can occur for number of reasons and does not necessarily imply that the data does not exists or is of default value.
>
> Details: IterationPath

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: Typically including the exact error you get helps in solving the issue

Comment: Hi James Z,.  The details of error are as follow, initially I used the simple query .

Comment: Hi James Z,.  The details of error are as follow, initially I used the simple query .=OData.feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/organization/project/_odata/V3.0-preview/workitemrevisions?$filter=workitemtype in ('User Story')",null,[implementation="2.0"])
It give error as:
 Data source error:A null value was found. For the property named 'AreaPath'which has expected type'EDM.string[nullable=false]'does not allow null values. 
   After that I used (Omitvalues=ODataOmitValues.nulls,ODataversion=4].

Comment: But after that it gives error as:
DataFormat.error=We expected property 'Iterationpath',but the OData service omitted it from the response data.This can occur for number of reasons and does not necessarily imply that the data does not exists or is of default value.
Details: IterationPath

Comment: You should edit the details into your question, instead of posting them into the comments